# TypeError: 'partic' object is not callable

Tags: python, pygame

my partic is my class and my partics is my list  I keep getting this  error

```
    partics.append(partic(70,90,100,100,white))
TypeError: 'partic' object is not callable
```

not sure why

here is part of where the error is comming from my main loop

```
# main loop
        
# our main loop
runninggame = True
while runninggame:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type ==  pygame.QUIT:
            runninggame = False


        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if greenbutton2.isOver(pos) or greenbutton3.isOver(pos) or greenbutton4.isOver(pos) or greenbutton5.isOver(pos) or greenbutton6.isOver(pos) or greenbutton7.isOver(pos) or greenbutton8.isOver(pos) or greenbutton9.isOver(pos) or greenbutton10.isOver(pos):
                score += 1
                cointext = font.render("" + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
                coinrect.center = ((100,50))
                if greenbutton8.isOver(pos):
                    partics.append(partic(70,90,100,100,white))


                if greenbutton9.isOver(pos):
                    partics.append(partic(190,90,100,100,white))


                if greenbutton10.isOver(pos):
                    partics.append(partic(335,90,100,100,white))



        
    for partic in partics:
        if partic.x == 70 and partic.x == 190 and partic.x == 335:
            print("hi!")
```

Comment: The problem is caused by the fact that a variable has the same name as the class. The name of the variable and the class is `partic`. Rename the class `partic` -> `Partic`. I mentioned this in one of your previous questions, but you ignored it.

Comment: Are you sure `partic` is a CLASS and not an INSTANCE object?   Perhaps you started out with `class Partic`, and created an instance with `partic = Partic()` somewhere?  Or did you mean to capitalize it in your append calls?

Comment: `partic` *was* a name for the class, but the `for` loop at the bottom rebinds the name to one of the instances added to `partics`. When the `while` loop repeats, you no longer have a reference to the class.

Answer (score 1):

You are rebinding the name of your class in the `for` loop. Either pick a different name for the loop index, or (better yet) give your class the name `Partic`; class names conventionally start with a capital letter.

Comment: I tried for     ```for partic in parts:
        if partic.x == 70 and partic.x == 190 and partic.x == 335:
            print("hi!")``` < I tried changing the list to parts and used the same class Partic but nothing getts printed out if my partics are all in those positions

Answer (score 0):

The class `partic` and the instance object `partic` have the same name. If you do this:

```py
for partic in partics:
```

you will no longer be able to use the `partic` class because `partic` is now an instance objec.

Rename the class `partic` to `Partic`:

<s>`class partic:`</s>

```py
class Partic:
```

<s>`partics.append(partic(70,90,100,100,white))`</s>

```py
partics.append(Partic(70,90,100,100,white))
```

---

The following code doesn't make sense:

> ```py
> for partic in partics:
>        if partic.x == 70 and partic.x == 190 and partic.x == 335:
>            print("hi!")
> ```

`partic` is an object each attribute of `partic` has a single value. Hence the value of `partic.x` cannot be 70 and 190 and 355 at the same time.
You can do something lik this:

```py
count = 0
for partic in partics:
    if partic.x in [70, 190, 335]:
        count += 1
if count == 3:
    print("hi!")
```

respectively

```py
count = sum([1 if partic.x in [70, 190, 335] else 0 for partic in partics])
if count == 3:
    print("hi!")
```

Comment: for Partic in partics:
        if Partic.x == 70 and Partic.x == 190 and Partic.x == 335:
            print("hi!")     < so is there no way for me to check if 3 of my partics are on those points

Comment: if I use the Partic and make another list For Partic in Parts: then check if my partics are on the x position nothing happens nothing gets printed out

Comment: I tried for ```for partic in parts:         if partic.x == 70 and partic.x == 190 and partic.x == 335:             print("hi!") ``` < I tried changing the list to parts and used the same class Partic but nothing getts printed out if my partics are all in those positions

Comment: @HabibIsmail I've extended the answer.